# How does the stargate ramp survive the unstable wormhole?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

It's been established that the unstable wormhole created during the activation of a stargate will vaporize anything in its path. If so, how does the ramp in the SGC gate room, which goes right through the ring, survive?

[image: gate room]

On a related note, how on Earth does the iris close with this thing? Does the rear part retract?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As you can see from the image below, the [unstable wormhole vortex](https://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Unstable_vortex) (known colloquially as the "kawoosh") comes out from the centre of the puddle, then retracts back into the centre. The ramp is below the area affected.

The ramp isn't a single piece, it has a small split in the middle through which the wormhole  (and iris) can extend.

[image: Kawoosh!]

It was a production oversight in the earliest episodes that the ramp went through the gate. In later episodes, you can see the split more clearly.

BEFORE
[image: Ramp going through the gate]

AFTER
[image: ramp is a bit off the gate]

You can also see in this [original concept art](https://www.liveauctioneers.com/item/7906155), that even offworld (typically stone) gate platforms are built with a small gap to allow the vortex to form

[image: gate concept art]

Comment: And yes, I'm aware that this hasn't always been the case. That's a simple production error; http://www.gateworld.net/gallery/albums/sg1_season1/102-TheEnemyWithin/screencaps/normal_sg1_102_463.JPG

Comment: Upvoted for the "kawoosh" (also because it's a good answer, but that's less fun).

Comment: @moogle - I like that it's Carter, basically one of the only people in the world who actually understands the underlying physics, that comes up with such an unscientific name for it!

Comment: @Richard That last comment would be valuable just sitting as part of the end of your answer, e.g.: _"This hasn't always been the case. That's a simple production error."_ - as is it might get obscured via the various comment-hiding mechanisms. It's also pretty valuable in explaining the photo in the question!

Comment: The ramp is still effectively burying the gate. This has always bothered me. It's also true of any off-world gate where the bottom section is entirely encompassed in the stone that makes up the ramp.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - That's true, but the vortex is only a micron thick. That kind of gap in a stone platform would be essentially invisible to the naked eye.

Comment: @HNL: Am I the only one who doesn't see what is supposed to be different between the BEFORE and AFTER captures?

Comment: @Thepopmachine - The piece of metal grating running through the gate in the earlier episode is contiguous. In the later episodes, there is a small split where the face of the wormhole would be.

Comment: That is ridiculously subtle.

Comment: @Richard: It seems unlikely that the gap would only be a micron thick as the alignment requirement would then be incredibly strict.

Comment: @ThePopMachine, it's kind of subtle, but when I realized what Richard was pointing out, it was such a 'duh' moment for me that I immediately saw the split.