# Why does the unstable vortex of the stargate not destroy the SGC iris?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

As the title says, why doesnt the iris get destroyed?

Comment: This might also interest you; [How does the stargate ramp survive the unstable wormhole?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/66889/how-does-the-stargate-ramp-survive-the-unstable-wormhole)

Comment: @Valorum That I saw when typing the question but not the duplicate one

Comment: It's always worth using the search box (top right) to see if there's anything you've missed :-)